# Render the new action in modal with foundation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

What i'm trying is when i click on the link to create a new post instead of loading the url i want to render it in a modal.

This is what i have tried

```
<%= link_to "Add a new venue", class:"button",'data-reveal-id' => 'newVenue'%>



<div id="newVenue" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   <%= render 'new'%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call to `render 'new'` you have to [provide the controller name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller), like:

```
render 'posts/new'
```

Assuming your controller is called `PostsController`. if it's `VenuesController` then:

```
render 'venues/new'
```

The slash let's `render` know you want to render an action instead of just a partial.

Another approach is to load the content via ajax. Detailed here in the docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

Look for the section "Ajax-based Reveal modals"